# “error” vs. “mistake”

Tags: word-choice, differences

I think I understand the difference between “error” and “mistake”, but today I saw [this article](https://medium.com/backchannel/the-view-from-the-front-seat-of-the-google-self-driving-car-46fc9f3e6088) about Google’s self-driving cars that has the following sentence:

> A lot of this won’t be a surprise, especially if you already know that driver *error* causes 94% of crashes.

(Here “driver” refers to a person who drives a car, not to a part of computer software.)

On the one hand, it looks like the author is a native speaker. But on the other hand, my intuition and understanding of English tells me that it is incorrect to use “error” there, isn’t it?

Comment: No *driver error causes 94% of accidents* is idiomatic. One definitely wouldn't say *driver mistake causes 94%...*. *Mistake* tends to be used for individual instances, but it is rarely used for driving matters. e.g. *It was a mistake to suggest they bring their dog with them for the evening*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word *error,* in the statement that “driver error causes 94% of crashes,” is being used as a [mass noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun). Though *error* and *mistake* are otherwise nearly synonymous, only the former has a mass-noun sense, numbered 2.a in [the online Merriam-Webster entry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/error):

> 2 a :  the quality or state of erring.

Thus *error* is indeed the correct choice, between the two, for this context.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct.
The speaker means that 94% of crashes happens because of bad judgement/wrong action/misconception on the part of the driver.